# vim and TeX filetypes: plaintex vs. tex

Tags: vim, latex, tex

I open `.tex` files with Vim, but some files are recognized as `filetype=plaintex` and others as `filetype=tex`. Why is this? What is the trigger that recognizes the file as tex, which has the highlighting I want?

Answer (score 31):

Why are some `.tex` files opened in Vim as `filetype=plaintex` and others as `filetype=tex`? Since the same extension, `.tex` in this case, is used for multiple filetypes, "Vim tries to guess what kind of file it is" according to the [Vim filetype-overrule documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/filetype.html#filetype-overrule).

The [ft-tex-plugin section of the Vim filetype documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/filetype.html#ft-tex-plugin) lists the rules used by Vim ([versions 7 and higher](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Vim)) to determine which filetype to use for `.tex` files:

1. If the first line of the file is `%&<format>` where `<format>` can be `plain`, `context`, or `latex`, then the filetype is set to plain TeX, ConTeXt, or LaTeX, respectively.
2. If there is no format designator command on the first line, then Vim searches the file for keywords to determine if the filetype should be set to `context` (ConTeXt) or `tex` (LaTeX).
3. If no keywords are found, the filetype is set to `plaintex` (plain TeX).

The last rule is important. If you create an empty `.tex` file using a command like `touch myfile.tex`, then when you open it in Vim the filetype will default to `plaintex`, since the file is blank.

You can change the default behavior by setting the global variable `tex_flavor` in your `.vimrc`:

- `let g:tex_flavor = "plain"`
- `let g:tex_flavor = "context"`
- `let g:tex_flavor = "latex"`

Answer (score 14):

Are you using the LaTeX-suite plugin? If so, then you probably want

`let g:tex_flavor='latex'`

in your .vimrc.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the LaTeX-suite plugin. See answer by Matthew Rankin or [`:h ft-tex-plugin`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/filetype.txt.html#ft-tex-plugin).

Comment: Certain plugins may not work with `plaintex`, which is the default value if no keyword is found. I find the setting in this answer helpful to consistently set `tex` to be the filetype  for a newly created `.tex` file. This helps Vimtex to work with the newly created file under the correct filetype.

Answer (score 3):

More than I ever wanted to know about this subject: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/filetype.html

> To disable one of the file types, add a line in your filetype file, 
>   see |remove-filetype|.